# Firestore and Datastore in the same GAE project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google App Engine project and I use Datastore.

I see that under the firebase console, I also have the option to create a Firestore database.

Does this Firestore database use the underlying Datastore in the same GAE project? I'm guessing maybe it lives side by side with Datastore?

That being said, can I use Firestore and Datastore in the same project?

Let me know if I am missing something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are related.

But in addition to not being able to use both in the same project you should be careful if/when you decide to switch as the switch isn't reversible (or at least not yet). Take the time to dive into the documentation to make an informed decision.

From [Choosing between Cloud Firestore and Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore):

> Cloud Firestore is the next major version of Cloud Datastore and a re-
>   branding of the product. Taking the best of Cloud Datastore and the
>   [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore), Cloud Firestore is a NoSQL document
>   database built for automatic scaling, high performance, and ease of
>   application development.

and

> **Warning**: Once your database option is set, you cannot switch. You can't use both Cloud Firestore and Cloud Datastore in the same
>   project.

Answer (score 4):

You can not.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#create_a_project):

> Cloud Firestore and App Engine: You can't use both Cloud Firestore and
>   Cloud Datastore in the same project, which might affect apps using App
>   Engine. Try using Cloud Firestore with a different project.