# How to use Firestore Database and Datastore in same Android App

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to use a Firestore database and Datastore in the same Android app. I know that it's not possible to use both in the same GCP project(explained here: [Firestore and Datastore in the same GAE project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735485/firestore-and-datastore-in-the-same-gae-project)) so I created two different projects, one for the Firestore and one for the Datastore. So now the problem is that I can't create a client Id for my Android app in both projects because of "duplicated fingerprints".

If I had just one project I normally would just login via Firebase AuthUi and then use the token from the FirebaseUser to build my service handler.

```
//login via FirebaseUI
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setTheme(getSelectedTheme())
                        .setLogo(getSelectedLogo())
                        .setAvailableProviders(getSelectedProviders())
                        .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(getSelectedTosUrl(),getSelectedPrivacyPolicyUrl())
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true,true)
                        .build(),

FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

Task<GetTokenResult> tokenResultTask =  firebaseUser.getIdToken(false);

tokenResultTask.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
       String result = task.getResult().getToken();

       //Creating the service object
       GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
       credential.setAccessToken(result);

        EndpointsApi.Builder builder  = new EndpointsApi.Builder(
                AppConstants.HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                AppConstants.JSON_FACTORY, credential);
        builder.setApplicationName("endpointsapi-server");
        return builder.build();
});
```

This works very well if I only have one project. But what to do if there are mutliple? The google-services.json is associated with the one project that also has the android client id, but the second project can't create an android client id using the same sha1 and package name(duplicated fingerprints).
If I just use the access token from the first project to build the service object(which belongs to the second project) I just get an error:

```
401 Unauthorized
    {
      "code": 401,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "Authorization required",
          "reason": "required"
        }
      ],
      "message": "Authorization required"
    }
```

which makes sense, because the second project doesn't know about the first one. Im lost on what to do to somehow use both at the same time.

In my web app I just whitelist the web client of the first project in the second one and then use the credentials of the first, obtained using firebase.AuthUi, to also login the second one. Which works.

```
this.uiConfig = {
      callbacks: {
        signInSuccess: (currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) => {
          const googleAuthcredential = 
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(credential['idToken']);      
          firebase.apps[1].auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(googleAuthcredential):

        }
      }
    };

this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
this.ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', this.uiConfig);
```

How to achieve the same thing in Android?

Thank you very much in advance.